# How can I pause the closing of RadWindow Close Event?

Tags: asp.net, .net, telerik, bootstrap-modal

I have used a Telerik RadWindow for adding details to my table.

I have a div for showing success or error message. Once I fill the table,  I need to show appropriate message in the div and then close the modal. But now the message is not displayed as the windows close soon after addition.

```
<script>    
    function GetRadWindow() {
        var oWindow = null;
        if (window.radWindow) 
            oWindow = window.radWindow;
        else if (window.frameElement.radWindow) oWindow = window.frameElement.radWindow;
            return oWindow;
    }

    function CloseModal() {
        var modalWindow = GetRadWindow();
        modalWindow.close(new Object);
    }
</script>

<div runat="server" id="message"></div>

If _result.Code = "00" Then
    Session("VoucherID") = _result.Result
    message.InnerHtml = "<div class='alert alert-success fade in alert-dismissable' id='alertWarningImmigration'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button><p style='margin-left:2%;' id='msg'><i class='fa fa-check pr10'></i>" & "Successfully added the Manual Online Payment.." & "</p></div>"
End If
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "myFunction", "CloseModal()", True)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep information in the dialog visible, you must not call its `close()` method (the `CloseModal` function in your case).

Some ideas that can help:

- use some timeout around `close()` to have the dialog close automatically after, let's say 4000ms
- use some callback from your div. For example, use the client-side click of an OK button in it to call the `CloseModal()` function.
- Use RadNotification for the message. It can close automatically after a set period of time and you can use its OnClientHidden event to call the `closeModal()` function. Showing the message is a one-liner on the server via its `Show("new message")` method.

On side note - depending on what you are trying to do, this may be interesting: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/window/how-to/confirm-closing